# sort list of class instances according to master list

Tags: python, list, class, sorting

I have a list of class instances like so:

```
classes = [A(someval), B(someval), C(someval)]
```

I would like to sort this list using a "master" list.

```
master_list = [B, A]
```

This would sort the list with `B` and  `A` first if they exist and always in the order specified in `master_list`. The classes are field validators so I expect there never to be more than one of each class, but one can never know for sure.

Any other class instances can just come after in any order they appear.

I would like to be able to put some instances at the end of the list according to another master list, but I suspect the best this to do here is just reverse the list and do the same thing again.

But how do I do it?

**Edit:** Subclasses are not important as these validator classes only have a single callable method and are generally pretty simple beasts. I have yet to encounter a subclassed validator and I have tried to imagine a scenario where it would be beneficial, but I cannot.

Comment: To clarify: the master list contains the classes, and the to-be-sorted list contains instances of those classes, yes?  What if the instance is a subclass, e.g., what if classes contains [A(someval), SubClassOfB(someval), C(someval)]?

Comment: So the output you would want would be `[B(someval), A(someval), C(someval)]`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes, that is correct. Or perhaps more like: `[<class 'B'>, <class 'A'>, <class 'C'>]` But I guess thats the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`index`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) function of the list class. Here's a simple example:

```
class A: pass
class B: pass
class C: pass

classes = [A(), B(), C()]
master_list = [B, A]

def sorter(instance):
    # get the type of the object
    c = instance.__class__
    # if it is in the master_list, use its index, otherwise put it at the end
    return master_list.index(c) if c in master_list else len(master_list)

final_list = sorted(classes, key=sorter)
```

final_list is now

```
[<__main__.B instance at 0x023348C8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x01EE64B8>, <__main__.C instance at 0x023348F0>]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def class_order(master_list):
    master_dict = { cls:i for (i, cls) in enumerate(master_list) }
    return lambda i: master_dict.get(i.__class__, len(master_list))

# I renamed ‘classes’ to ‘instances’ because it makes more sense.
sorted(instances, key=class_order(master_list))
```

This assumes that only direct instances of classes in master_list appear in the original list. If something derived from A or B appears, they won't sort as As or Bs, which they should.

Comment: The nice thing about this one is that you can make subclassing work by fiddling with the dictionary to include MRO entries.  Of course the whole thing gets rather undefined if there's a `class Urk(A,B)`...

Comment: @torek: That's an excellent point. Growing the dict as I observed new instances occurred to me, but a reason to do so didn't.

Comment: (PS: typo of sorts, line 2 should read `master_dict` not `dict`; and `list` on line 1 is not used)

Comment: If someone comes yelling at me to implement support for subclassed validators, I will be using this. But until then, the other way reads more clearly to my eyes. Thanks for your time, all of you.